# Laravel 5.5 При post запросе добавляются новые сессии

Tags: laravel, postgresql, сессия

Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем, может быть, проблема?

Я прохожу аутентификацию. У меня создается запись в таблице sessions.

[image: У меня создается запись в таблице sessions.]

Но если я отправлю какой-нибудь post запрос, у меня добавляется еще две сессии.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сессию пока нигде не использую. Единственное, что я изменил app/Http/Kernel.php

```
    protected $middlewareGroups = [
    'web' => [
        \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
        \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
        \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
        \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
        \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
        \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
    ],

    'api' => [
        \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class, // TODO https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33130748/laravel-session-id-changes-with-each-request
        \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class, // TODO https://kfirba.me/blog/the-undocumented-authenticatesession-middleware-decoded
        \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
        \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
        \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
        'bindings',
    ],
];
```

Answer (score 0):

Вдруг кому-то пригодится мой опыт и решение проблемы. Мы используем api. Работаем через postman. В тестовых запросах у нас существует pre-request Script. Pre-request Script дополнительно отправляет запросы на сервер, где они обрабатываются. Поэтому и создаются дополнительные сессии, которые не принадлежат аутентифицированному пользователю.